# Organising multiple conditions in componentDidUpdate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have multiple conditions in my componentDidUpdate():

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.something !== this.state.something) {
        // do something
    }

    if (prevProps.something !== this.props.something) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

I imagine it can grow quite long if there's a lot of prevState/prevProps comparison when the component updates.

Is there a better way to organise the code inside it or is this just the way it is?

Comment: You can certainly group these blocks into functions i.e. `this.checkStateA(prevState)`, `this.checkPropsColor(prevProps)` etc. No need to keep your code inside these predefined function names.

Comment: What scenario are you requiring to check every prop that changed?

If you need a unique action for each one than there's no getting around the code, but i'd question the architecture you could definitely do it a better way... Otherwise if you just need one action if any change you can just map through and check them all

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way of reducing that code. Rather, what you can do is store everything in one state, like an array. SO that you can use only one state for components to get updated.

Consider there is state called something which stores the below data.

```
something: {
    var1: "...",
    var2: "...",
    arr: [ "var1": "...",
           "var2": "..." 
         ],
    num1: '20', 
    .... };
```

Such that you can call only once like below or else you can call multiple times:

```
componentDidUpdate (prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.something !== this.props.something) {
      ...
    }
}
```